# Dealing with changing data (concurrency) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, concurrency, notifications

I need some guidance with regard to data changes in iOS Swift. I know that there are 3 or more methods to get a screen to refresh it's data, including notifications and protocols/delegates. However, I'm struggling with determining which approach is most applicable and efficient in real world situations.

I have a tabbed application where the first tab is a calendar of appointments. The appointments are stored in MySQL on a remote server. On first access, I retrieve all appointments and store them in core data. I display them on the calendar from core data. However, the appointment data could be changing in the background.

Situation 1: A different tab in the app could create, change, or remove an appointment.

Possible solutions:

1. Update core data and have calendar refresh from core data on ViewDidAppear?
2. Local notification to alert calendar of a change?
3. Some type of protocol/delegate approach?
4. Have calendar check for any changes since ... and update core data every time it is displayed?
5. Other?

Situation 2: Someone else could have created or updated an appointment on the server database.

1. Database trigger sends remote notification to tell calendar to pick up updates?
2. Calendar checks for new/changed data in ViewDidAppear?
3. Other?

For prototyping purposes, I have the calendar refreshing itself from the server whenever it is displayed, which is, of course, not very efficient. Can anyone recommend a more efficient approach to maintaining current data and handling background changes? Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend having your view controllers respond to CoreData's notification: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification

Comment: Use `NSFetchedResultsController` and implement its `delegate` methods for updating your table's datasource whenever there is a change.

Comment: And use a remote notification from the server to notify your app of server data changes

Comment: Thanks, guys. It all makes sense. However, how/when do you refresh the complete contents in core data, assuming changes were made while you had your phone off? Do you store a "last retrieved" date and then grab anything that has changed since then, or just grab everything, wipe core data, and re-load?